# snowflake - modify a data type from VARCHAR(16777216) to NUMBER

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to modify type VARCHAR(16777216)  to NUMBER in snowflake .

ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ALTER [COLUMN_NAME] set data type NUMBER;
returns : SQL compilation error: cannot change column [COLUMN_NAME] from type VARCHAR(16777216) to NUMBER(38,0)

also
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ALTER [COLUMN_NAME] set data type VARCHAR(500);
returns: SQL compilation error: cannot change column [COLUMN_NAME] from type VARCHAR(16777216) to VARCHAR(500) because reducing the byte-length of a varchar is not supported.

(I know I can add a new column to the table and then update it and remove the old one but I want to keep the column in its ordinal position not move to last column,
also I know I can create new table with the new data type and then insert the data to it but there is a lot of data and more then one table I need to do this change on .. so I prefer to avoid this solutions)

is there an easy way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're aware of this, but in Snowflake there's not much difference between making a new table and copying the data and changing the data type. The DB files Snowflake uses to store data cannot be updated, so any data update will cause a new file with the data being created (and if there's more than 1 record in that file it means the data will get split between 2 files causing performance degradation)

And for that reason there isn't really an "easy" way, because anything you can think of will cause a total table overhaul if you try to change the data type.